# overlapping repeating frames oracle reports

Tags: oracle, report

I have 2 repeating frames and the first one is rendered on the top of the second one. I need the second repeating frames to be rendered after the first repeating frame ends. I cannot make it static, it must be dynamic or can be static if I can say that the second repeating frame moves in X position.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not that your frames are repeating, but that their container frames are potentially overlapping.

When one frame expands (e.g. because it contains a repeating frame), you want other frames (that are on the side or below of it) to move to accommodate it.

To do this, put each of your repeating frames within their own non-repeating frame, and make sure these "container" frames are not overlapping.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24269_01/doc.11120/e24480/orbr_concepts1008.htm#RSBDR214

Comment: i did it. Also I put an anchor between them, thank you